# Change java locale settings

Tags: java, locale

Is it possible somehow change java locale settings like currency symbol or decimal separator. I mean not from java program, but using java configuration files or environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that can be done, but why do you want to change them anyways? That's what locale is all about. I believe you need to just figure out a correct locale to work with.

If you need a decimal to be written as a comma (`,`) use the `Locale.GERMAN` instead of going and chainging the decimal separator of `Locale.CHINESE`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `user.language` and `user.country` java system properties.

For example, to use the German locale, start java with `-Duser.language=de -Duser.country=DE`